# How to open pdf on a specific page using Tkinter and tkPDFViewer

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, tkpdfviewer

I have written a python script able to open pdf files in a Tkinter window using tkPDFViewer. Now I want to make it open a pdf file on a specific page. Any ideas?

Comment: The `tkPDFViewer` module is comprised of a single 87 line source file named [`tkPDFViewer.py`](https://github.com/Roshanpaswan/tkPDFViewer/blob/main/tkPDFViewer/tkPDFViewer.py) which uses the PyMuPDF package internally — the latter being a Python binding for MuPDF, which is a lightweight PDF viewer —  to read the pages of PDF files and convert them into displayable images in a background thread which is started when the `start_pack()` method of an instance of the `ShowPdf` class it defines is called. You could probably modify how that works to do what you want.

Comment: @martineau thank you for your reaction with my post. I will try to do so and give you my feedback

Comment: @KJ thanks, I will try and give you my feedback

Comment: My explanation of how it works wasn't accurate. `start_pack()` isn't a method of `ShowPdf`, it's a nested function which is called automatically when the `pdf_view()` method of a `ShowPdf`  instance is called. A background thread inserts an image of each page in the PDF file into a `Text` widget at the end — so when it's finished the last page is probably what it visible. You could add an optional keyword argument to `pdf_view()` method calls that specified what page to display once they have all been inserted and use its value to vertically scroll the `Text` widget to the desired page.

Comment: "Now I want to make it open a pdf file on a specific page": do you want to display only a specific page or do you want to move the view to a specific page after displaying the whole file?

Comment: @j_4321 I want to move the view to a specific page after displaying the whole file

Answer (score 0):

The `ShowPdf` class stores the images correspodning to each page in the list `self.img_object_li` and displays them in a `Text` widget. Therefore, you can use

```
 self.text.see(self.img_object_li[<page nb> - 1])
```

to move the display to the desired page. You can add this command at the end of `add_img()` in `tkPDFViewer`'s source code to initialize the view at a given page of the document. You can also define a `goto(page)` method like in the example below to switch page after loading the document:

```
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf
from tkinter import Tk, Button


class ShowPdf(pdf.ShowPdf):
    def goto(self, page):
        try:
            self.text.see(self.img_object_li[page - 1])
        except IndexError:
            if self.img_object_li:
                self.text.see(self.img_object_li[-1])

root = Tk()

pdfviewer = ShowPdf()
# Add your pdf location and width and height.
pdfframe = pdfviewer.pdf_view(root, pdf_location=r"/path/to/document.pdf", width=80, height=50)
pdfframe.pack()


Button(root, text="Go to page 3", command=lambda: pdfviewer.goto(3)).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. it really helps me. I just want to know if I can use the invoke method to  this button so it will be clicked automaticaly

Comment: You need to wait until the pdf is fully loaded before you can invoke the button/call directly `goto()` and it is not straightforward to know when that is since `tkPDFViewer` loads the pdf in a thread. If you want to do that, it is easier to modify directly the source code of `tkPDFviewer` instead of using the library and execute `goto(<page>)` at the end of the `add_img()` function (in `pdf_view()`).